# Search table content based on select item and search box

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-data-tables

I am trying to create a select and search box for a data table in vue js. The items of select options are the column headers of the table.When we select one option(one column header), and search in the input box, we need to search in that particular column only. For example, ID,Name and Occupation are three columns in table, if we select Name in select options, we can search for names in input field. I am sharing my code here ,could any one please help me with this

I have used Vuetify and Vue js2 for the code

```
<template>
<v-flex xs6>
        <v-select
          v-model="e1"
          :items="states"
          menu-props="auto"
          label="Select"
          hide-details
          prepend-icon="map"
          single-line
        ></v-select>
      </v-flex>
<v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            :counter="10"
            label="First name"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
  <v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    item-key="name"
    select-all
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td>
        <v-checkbox
          v-model="props.selected"
          primary
          hide-details
        ></v-checkbox>
      </td>
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
search: ''
        states: [
          'Calories','Fat','Carbs','Protein','Iron'
        ]
      }
        selected: [],
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'left',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name'
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%'
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<v-flex xs6>
      {{searchField}}
      {{search}}
      <v-select
        v-model="searchField"
        :items="states"
        menu-props="auto"
        label="Select"
        hide-details
        prepend-icon="map"
        single-line
        @change="search=''"
      ></v-select>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        :counter="10"
        label="First name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="table_data"
      item-key="name"
      select-all
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>
          <v-checkbox
            v-model="props.selected"
            primary
            hide-details
          ></v-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>


data() {
      return {
        dialog: false,
        search: '',
        states: [
          'Calories', 'Fat', 'Carbs', 'Protein', 'Iron'
        ], selected: [],
        searchField: '',
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'left',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name'
          },
          {text: 'Calories', value: 'calories'},
          {text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat'},
          {text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs'},
          {text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein'},
          {text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron'}
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%'
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%'
          }
        ],
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name'
          },
          {text: 'Calories', align: 'center', value: 'calories'},
          {text: 'Fat (g)', align: 'center', value: 'fat'},
          {text: 'Carbs (g)', align: 'center', value: 'carbs'},
          {text: 'Protein (g)', align: 'center', value: 'protein'},
          {text: 'Actions', align: 'left', value: 'name', sortable: false}
        ],
      }
    }

computed: {

      table_data() {
        let self = this;
        let filtered_data = this.desserts.filter(function (item) {
          if (self.searchField && self.search != '') {
            console.log(item[self.searchField.toLowerCase()])
            console.log(self.search)
            return item[self.searchField.toLowerCase()] == self.search;
          }
          else {
            return item
          }
        });
        return filtered_data;
      }
    },
```